# AntiVirus ProgressBar

Tags: c#, progress-bar, antivirus

I have to add a progress Bar in my AV and the problem is that I don't know in advance how many files to scan.So I don't know the total count.If I count the files to be scanned,then the soft pauses for a while since it has to go through many files and in case of Full System Scan,this pause if of long duration which is not desired.Hence I dropped that code.I heard that avast dynamically changes progress bar value i.e. if the value approaches 100 and more files are found to scan then it pushes the value to like 50.Coding is in C#.

Comment: You are making your own anti-virus software and don't know how to get the number of files on the system? What is more depressing is you are trying to do this in C#.  If scanning the system causes a pause it means your scan thread is blocking the ui thread, you should solve that, before you worry about a progress bar.

Comment: Why not use two threads, one for AV and one that will find out the number of files to be scanned and that will increase the max value of the progress bar. You can't know for sure what the number of files will be as the user may create/delete files while your scan is in progress.

Comment: @Ramhound-you didn't got what I was saying..I know how to get the total number of files,I am doing it recursively but when i count them within the recursive loop,due to thousands of files,I am experiencing a pause because of that counting loop.After that there is no problem in scanning.Scanning is fine –

Comment: @AndyChora - If a recursive loop is causing a pause then its not thread safe. I still feel its weird that you are trying to make some as advanced as a anti-virus program at your skill level. If you are using a recursive function to count the files you are doing it wrong.(at least in my opionion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be foolish to try to get a list of all the files in one pass, before updating the UI at all.

Use threads; one to locate files and add their locations to a queue, and update a total file count.

Another to do the scanning, and update the count of scanned files.

and the UI thread will update itself based on that; so the upper bound will constantly be increasing... or, becoming more accurate.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution.  It would cost very little to calculate the number of files that need to be scanned.  You could even locate then scan the file, you might even be able to use the index service built into windows, to determine the number of files.

Comment: and don't forget proper synchronization of ddata across the threads too.

Answer (score 1):

Just count the folders 5-level deep, and calculate the progress based on how many of those folders were scanned. Increase dept to increase accuracy (at the cost of pre-calculation time). Use this article to learn how to enumerate directories as fast as possible: [MSDN How to: Enumerate Directories and Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking how much occupied space there is on the disk and evaluating number of files basing on density: files per GB. At first You have to make an assumption how much files do get stored in one GB (for my system it is 3860) During the scan you will know what is real density of scanned hard drive so you can adjust number of files.

Adjusting total number of files during the scan is the best method I can think off, and being user of you app I would like it much more, than waiting until you count all the files on the machine.

Comment: This would be worse, except for a full disk scan.

Comment: My solution helps with issue of not showing any progress bar during period of checking how much files will be scanned.

Proposition of using two threads is a UI or performance tip, and says nothing about number of files to scan. BTW, using two threads, when both are IO demanding won't speed up a lot.

As always, when you have an issue like that the best thing you can do it test possible options.

Comment: Simple logic: adding up the size of a list of files requires first knowing what files to add up. That will take much more effort (relatively) than simply knowing the number of files. Again, unless you are only talking about full disk scans.

Answer (score 0):

Since AV scans should happen on a regular basis can you just remember how many files were in the last scan and then pad it by 5%?  That would give the user a rough idea of how long it would take without having to do an up to date full scan right now.  In order to get an accurate number for the first scan you would have to do a full directory search and suffer the pause that you described.  As for custom individual folders you could either store the # of files for the first 2-3 levels of folders and then just do a directory scan below that as there would be a reduced number of files in each sub-directory.

Comment: Which means the original question still stands, and isn't answered.

Comment: But what about custom scan where the user selects a particular folder..How to keep track of all the folders and files within them? Are you saying that only for full Scan I can use what you have said.Looks interesting So could you please elaborate it bro

Comment: It is an idea different than yours, the OP can determine the merits of the idea based on all the facts that he has and hasn't told us about.  The caveats are clearly made by both the overall language and the term "rough idea".